# GitHub Actions : git pull on the server

Tags: github, continuous-deployment, github-actions

I have a personal website on a GitHub repo called `personal-website` and every-time I am making changes locally, I have to SSH into my server (DigitalOcean), go to `var/www/personal-website` and make a `git pull`.

I am trying to find a way to `pull` from the `master` every-time there is a `push` into the same branch. I read about GitHub actions and wrote a file on `.github/workflows/devops.yml`

```
name: Build and Deploy

on:
    push:
        branches: master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

**GitHub Actions result of Build and Deploy job**
[image]

On my GitHub Actions page, the job is successful. However, there is no automatic pull request that is done on the server side. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a .sh script and do git pull / git commit / git push